# Not getting LEFT JOIN query in LINQ to pick up empty rows

Tags: .net, linq

This is the SQL query I am trying to convert into a LINQ query:

```
SELECT
    ContactID,
    COUNT (ls.SoldToContactID) AS Count
FROM
    Contacts c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LeadSales ls on c.ContactID = ls.SoldToContactID
GROUP BY 
    c.ContactID
```

I'm getting the results expected from `leadSales`, but I am not picking up any of the rows from `contacts` that have no match in `leadSales`.

```
var leadSales = (IQueryable of the LeadSales table)
var contacts = (IQueryable of the Contacts table)

BuyerList = from ls in leadSales
    join contact in contacts on ls.SoldToContactID equals contact.ContactID into sb
    from subBuyer in sb.DefaultIfEmpty()
        group ls by new {
            subBuyer.ContactID,
            FirstName = subBuyer.FirstName,
            LastName = subBuyer.LastName
        } into g
        select new LeadBuyersByStateItem
        {
            ContactID = g.Key.ContactID,
            Name = g.Key.LastName + ", " + g.Key.FirstName,
            LeadsCount = g.Count()
        };
```

**EDIT:**

Based on feedback from Ivan, I now have this:

```
BuyerList = from contact in contacts
                        join ls in leadSales on contact.ContactID equals   ls.SoldToContactID into c_ls
                        from ls in c_ls.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        group contact by new
                        {
                            ls.Contact.ContactID,
                            FirstName = ls.Contact.FirstName,
                            LastName = ls.Contact.LastName
                        } into g
                        select new LeadBuyersByStateItem
                        {
                            ContactID = g.Key.ContactID,
                            Name = g.Key.LastName + ", " + g.Key.FirstName,
                            LeadsCount = g.Count()
                        };
```

But, this is throwing this error:

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Comment: You don't give up :) I could close it for the 3rd time because it's still a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq. Instead, this time I'll give you a hint: `from c in contacts join ls in leadSales on c.ContactID equals ls.SoldToContactID into c_ls from ls in c_ls.DefaultIfEmpty() ...`. Hope you can manage it from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: @Ivan, I had already tried that after your last comment (the second time). Screw it. I'm just going to use the SQL and forget LINQ.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Hmm, it works usually. What ORM are you using?

Comment: Entity Framework.  I was getting a null error -- don't recall now.  I've moved on. Sometimes just using good ol fashioned SQL is so much easier that LINQ.

Comment: Hopefully not EF Core? Because it's known to have currently problems with `left outer join`. Why don't you forget about the SQL query and joins, and use simply `from c in contacts select new LeadBuyersByStateItem { ContactId = c.ContactID, Name = c.LastName + ", " + c.FirstName, LeadsCount = leadSales.Count(ls => ls.SoldToContactID == c.ContactID) }`? Simple, and no way EF to make a mistake :)
,

Comment: No, not core.  I'll post what I have now, and the error it's throwing

Comment: See edit to the OP

Comment: I am testing your suggestion

Comment: This worked!!! `from c in contacts select new LeadBuyersByStateItem { ContactId = c.ContactID, Name = c.LastName + ", " + c.FirstName, LeadsCount = leadSales.Count(ls => ls.SoldToContactID == c.ContactID) }`  Wow that is so much simpler. Thank you!  If you post as the answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the initial LINQ query is that you have exchanged the left and right parts, so it was equivalent of SQL `LeadSales LEFT OUTER JOIN Contacts`.

The problem with the updated query is that the `group by` clause is using `ls.Contact`, and since `ls` is the right end of the left outer join, it can be `null`. To match the SQL query, use `contact` variable (the left end of the join which is guaranteed to exist). Also note that SQL `COUNT(ls.SoldToContactID)` is excluding `NULL` values, so you have to account that in the LINQ query (there is no direct LINQ equivalent construct).

So the direct LINQ translation of the SQL query is like this:

```
from c in contacts
join ls in leadSales on c.ContactID equals ls.SoldToContactID into c_ls
from ls in c_ls.DefaultIfEmpty()
group ls by new
{
    c.ContactID,
    c.FirstName,
    c.LastName
} into g
select new LeadBuyersByStateItem
{
    ContactID = g.Key.ContactID,
    Name = g.Key.LastName + ", " + g.Key.FirstName,
    LeadsCount = g.Count(ls => ls != null)
};
```

But if you forget the SQL query and concentrate on the desired result, you'll see that there are simpler LINQ / EF versions of the same query.

The easiest is if you have navigation property from `Contact` to `LeadSale` (I've noticed you have from `LeadSale` to `Contact`) like

```
public ICollection<LeadSale> LeadSales { get; set; }
```

Then the query is simply:

```
from c in contacts
select new LeadBuyersByStateItem
{
    ContactID = c.ContactID,
    Name = c.LastName + ", " + c.FirstName,
    LeadsCount = c.LeadSales.Count()
};
```

If you don't have such property, you can use `Count` with condition:

```
from c in contacts
select new LeadBuyersByStateItem
{
    ContactID = c.ContactID,
    Name = c.LastName + ", " + c.FirstName,
    LeadsCount = leadSales.Count(ls => ls.SoldToContactID == c.ContactID)
};
```

or [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_1):

```
from c in contacts
join ls in leadSales on c.ContactID equals ls.SoldToContactID into c_ls
select new LeadBuyersByStateItem
{
    ContactID = c.ContactID,
    Name = c.LastName + ", " + c.FirstName,
    LeadsCount = c_ls.Count()
};
```

To recap, in all cases you should start the LINQ query with the required table.